# How to allow multiple spaces between colon and value

Tags: javascript, eslint

Globally I'd like to force `{key: value}` except in a few places where the following will be valid:

```
schema = {
    id:          Joi.string(),
    title:       Joi.string(),
    description: Joi.string(),
    start:       Joi.date().iso(),
    end:         Joi.date().iso(),
    creator:     Joi.object(),
    archived:    Joi.boolean(),
    _actions:    Joi.array()
};
```

Looking through the docs (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/key-spacing.html) I can't see if there's a combination of `align` and `beforeColon`, `afterColon` that works.

My config file rule is:

```
"key-spacing": [2, {"beforeColon": false, "afterColon": true}]
```

I've trying to override it for a given file with:

```
/* eslint key-spacing: ????? */
```

Is this rule possible?

Comment: yes you can override it for a file by defining the rule at top of the file. You can do `align: value` in that.

Comment: I tried. That's what was failing. I'll try again.

Comment: if you can share exactly how you are doing will help.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `mode` option to `minimum` to require one *or more* spaces:

```
"key-spacing": [2, {"beforeColon": false, "afterColon": true, "mode": "minimum"}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Tamlyn, will try this and report back.